# Some fonts and symboles are missing while opening the Xlsx File on libre-Office and WPS Office ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, libreoffice, wps-office

I have installed all the fonts and symbols using font-manager and also install all windows fonts in my system still content in xlsx file not showing correctly

error is showing continuously "Libre Office required more fonts " by ubuntu software

"some symbols and fonts are missing" by the WPS office

Answer (score 0):

Need more info: Where did you get your microsoft fonts? If you dual boot and just linked to your Windows 10 fonts directory, it doesn't have everything that Win 7 did, and Win 7 didn't have every font that Microsoft office had. I'm not sure which versions are most complete, but on my openSUSE machine, LibreOffice and WPS Office are happy with my fonts from Win 7 + Office 2013. Formatting still needs to be touched up, though.